# Permissibility of hiring man and woman to work together online

Tags: fiqh, hanafi, men-women

Salaam alaikum

I am looking to hire software engineers to work on an Android app. Alhamdulilah, I found two Muslim candidates, which is ideal since this is to work with the Quran.

One is male, the other female. Is it OK to hire both to work together even if it's just online? Or is it preferable not to? My gut tells me not to, but I wanted to check to see if I was being overly cautious.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is permissible that

- men and women work at the same place
- men and women may exchange on-line about any subject of general interest or opinion, except establishing an intimate relationship.

It will be the responsibility of the employees to observe the limits. It would thus be fair to have their agreement to the working condition.

https://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=9384&LangID=2

https://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=9386&LangID=2